# Can two workflows simultaneously exist for a sharepoint document?

Tags: sharepoint, workflow

Can two workflows simultaneously exist for a sharepoint document?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but they must be two distinct workflows. While a workflow is running and associated with a document, you may not rerun / reassociate that workflow with the same document again.